# Bring back the sum of values from another sheet

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a list of items with a value assigned to each in one spreadsheet and in the other I have a smaller list of items that are used on that day.

e.g.

**SHEET 1**

```
ITEM       PRICE
Apple       10
Banana      20
Pear        30
Sofa       100
Coca Cola   10
```

**SHEET 2**

ITEMS BOUGHT

```
Apple
Pear
Sofa
```

TOTAL COST = (value of Apple + Pear + Sofa)

I want to total the values from sheet 1 that correlates to the values in Sheet 2, in the example above I'd have 140. I don't want to have to copy the prices across onto the second sheet, I'd like to just type in (or use a drop down) the item and it will automatically total up the cost.

It's basically a Vlookup but I'm not just looking at one value I could be looking at 10-20.

Any suggestions would be very welcome!

I've tried googling this but it's an absolute nightmare to explain on a search bar and find something similar.

**EDIT:**

I have figured it out!

For the total I use:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A2:A8,Sheet1!A2:A35)>0, Sheet1!B2:B35))
```

Where `Sheet2!A2:A8` is my list of items I want to get the total price for, `Sheet1!A2:A35` is the list of items I want to search againsts and the `Sheet1!B2:B35` is the values that I want to sum.

Comment: Does the answer need to be in a new sheet or can it be in either of the other sheets

Comment: Ideally the answer would be in the same sheet as the smaller list. But it could go anywhere tbh.

Comment: Can you elaborate about various conditions to sum the values? From the question, it appear as if you simply want to sum Apple and Pear values.

Comment: There are no conditions, what I put in my "smaller" list will be depend on a day to day basis, it could contain 1 item or it could contain 20. A better example would be that the values are prices and my second sheet is a shopping list of items and I want to total the price of all my items. I know this can easily be done by simply looking up the value of each, putting it next to each item and then total that up, however I want to keep it in one column. 

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your question has the second list as a side-by-side list (Apple in A, Pear in B)

Comment: Yeah, I had to add two breaks to get it to go down another line. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I've rejigged it and will update my Answer, hopefully this is now suitable.

Comment: I have figured it out!

For the total I use:

  =SUM(IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A2:A8,Sheet1!A2:A35)>0, Sheet1!B2:B35))
Where Sheet2!A2:A8 is my list of items I want to get the total price for, Sheet1!A2:A35 is the list of items I want to search againsts and the Sheet1!B2:B35 is the values that I want to sum.

Comment: Try this for a non-array version `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Sheet1!A2:A35,Sheet2!A2:A8,Sheet1!B2:B35))`

Comment: Thanks Barry, that works a treat!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, hope this is now correct:

The formula you need is on the smalller sheet and uses `INDEX` and `MATCH` to lookup the value from `Sheet1` using the following formula for the first item which can be copied down:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet2!A4,Sheet1!$A:$A,0))`

The total has a simple formula: `=SUM(B:B)`

A screen shot is provided below.

[image]

Comment: It's pulling through the values correctly, all that's missing is a total, right?

Comment: pressed enter too early! That's not quite what I need. I just need ONE total. If I had a huge range of fruit in the first list with the price of each, and on the second list was just a smaller list of fruit that, for example, I bought. I want to get the total value that I spent by looking the fruit up from my list and pulling back the prices and totalling them from the larger sheet.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah. I could do it that way and lookup the fruit and bring back the price and then total it at the bottom, but was looking to just have a list of the items and then total at the bottom. i.e. keep it to one Column.

Comment: One column?  Your example has the Apple, Pear in a ROW (i.e. side-by-side) so that's how I structured the answer.  A simple `=SUM(3:3)` would calculate a total for the row of looked up values

Comment: Apologies, I didn't have enough line breaks to push it down to the next column. It doesn't always appear the way it looks in edit!

Comment: OK.  You can copy and paste your Excel table into the Question and then format it using the curly brackets {} for future reference...

Comment: Is there a way of just having the list of items and the total, WITHOUT putting the prices in the second sheet? That is really the issue i'm trying to solve. Like a vlookup, but i'm looking up multiple items at the same time and bringing back the sum of all items found.

Comment: Hide column B? Change the colour of the font to white? Reference from another sheet?  I've answered the original question and a revised version, that's my lot I'm afraid.

Comment: I'd prefer not to. I might end up having to! There must be a way of looking up a list of items and bringing back their corresponding values! hmmm I think your on the right track with the index + match, I'll have to just look over it more!

Comment: An upvote or an accept of the answer would be sufficient thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Considering `I know this can easily be done by simply looking up the value of each, putting it next to each item and then total that up, however I want to keep it in one column`: maybe:

```
=SUM(('Sheet 1'!$B$1:$B$5)*((rng=A3)+(rng=A4)+(rng=A5)+(rng=A6)))
```

where `rng` is the named range for the values, `ITEMS BOUGHT` is in A2, the OR conditions are increased to suit and $B$5 adjusted to suit. To be entered with CSE.